# Calculated field in model class gives exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm getting the exception when executing Linq query:

> The specified type member 'Active' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Model class

```
public class User : Entity
{
     //Many properties skipped

     [NotMapped]
        public bool Active
        {
            get
            {
               return Orders.Any(c => 
                c.Active && (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order ||
                             c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription));
            }
        }

}
```

The Linq query which gives exception

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetInactiveUsersForSuspensionNotification()
{
    return _userRepository.GetAll()
        .Include(i=>i.Orders)
        .Where(w => w.Active == false);
}
```

`Orders` is a related table to `Users`.

Answer (score 10):

When using LINQ to Entities the LINQ expression is converted to a SQL query to be sent to the database. This is so that the whole table is not pulled into memory.

Your problem is that because Active is not mapped the database knows nothing about it and therefore cannot make the calculation.

You will either need to move Active into your DB or change the LINQ statement to only query on columns that are in your DB